# The opposite of the right ideal in the ring of 2x2 matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Since every ring has an opposite, I would like to know:

1. Which is the opposite of the rings of $n \times n$ matrices? More specifically, of the $2 \times 2$ matrices.
2. Is there an opposite for the right ideal of rings of  $2 \times 2$ matrices which is made up of a matrix with zeroes in the bottom
   row? If so, which one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) The matrix ring $M_n(K)$ is isomorphic to its opposite ring via $A\mapsto A^T$.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I am asking about the opossite ring and how it looks like, not about isomorphisms

Comment: An isomorphism from the opposite ring to a known ring precisely answers the question how the opposite ring "looks like".

Comment: 2) What does "is there an opposite" mean? A right ideal of any ring automatically is a left ideal of its opposite ring.

Comment: @DietrichBurde we should be careful to posit that K has to be commutative (or has an involution, or some other sufficient condition) for that to hold, but yeah.

Comment: If you still want an answer to the second question, you should explain what you mean by "opposite of a right ideal"